How to get the Authorization key value from the response headers
The Network tab shows the header but unable to get the header in frontend(Next js)

But when I am console the response headers then this thing is showing.

Here is my code of frontend(Next js)
try {
  var path = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_PATH;
  const response = await axios.post(
    `${path}/api/User/login`,
    {
      email: values.loginUsername,
      password: values.loginPassword,
    },
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      withCredentials: true,
    }
  );

  console.log('---responseHeader----', JSON.stringify(response.headers, null, 2));

  // Get the authorization header from the response
  const authorizationHeader = response.headers['authorization'] || response.headers['Authorization'];
  console.log("Authorization header:", authorizationHeader);
  
  // Extract the token from the authorization header
  if (authorizationHeader) {
    const token = authorizationHeader.split('Bearer ')[1];
    localStorage.setItem('authToken', token);
  }

  // Extract the role from the response data and set it in local storage
  const userData = response.data;
  if (userData.role) {
    localStorage.setItem('userRole', userData.role);
  }

  // Optionally, perform any action after successful POST
  router.push('/');
} catch (error) {
  if (axios.isAxiosError(error) && error.response) {
    formik.setFieldError('loginPassword', 'Username and password do not match.');
    console.error('Error:', error.response.statusText);
  } else {
    formik.setFieldError('loginPassword', 'Username and password do not match.');
  }
}

here is my server code (.yaml)file
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: "Authorization"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "Content-Type, Authorization"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "url"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"

And here is the configuration for the cors in C# .NET
app.UseCors(options =>
  {
      options.WithOrigins(corsSettings.BackendUrl, corsSettings.FrontendUrl);
      options.AllowAnyMethod();
      options.AllowAnyHeader();
      options.WithExposedHeaders("Authorization");
  });


could you please also share the content of the response along with the response.headers with console.log(response)

Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization is lacking, despite your options.WithExposedHeaders("Authorization"). Perhaps the particular header name is a problem? I expect Authorization only in requests, not in responses.
